# How to construct a Dirichlet series that cannot be analytically continued beyond its abscissa of absolute convergence?

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-number-theory, dirichlet-series

If I want a power series $\sum_n a_n \, z^n$ that cannot be analytically continued anywhere beyond its disk of convergence $|z| < R$, then I can use a [lacunary series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lacunary_function), e.g., $\sum_n z^{2^n}$.

Are there any similar techniques for constructing a Dirichlet series $\sum_n a_n / n^s$ that cannot be analytically continued beyond its abscissa of absolute convergence?

(I'm sorry if this question is a bit open-ended, but I want to avoid getting a full answer to my homework question.)

Comment: One easy way is to take a known dirichlet series with one singularity (eg zeta with pole at $1$) and shift it so it has singularities at a countable dense set of points on the line $1$ and then put small positive coefficients to make the corresponding series still absolute convergent

Comment: @Conrad: Thanks!